# Validating free time slot in schedule

Tags: javascript, algorithm, go, calendar

I am trying to come up with an efficient algorithm to do the following, ideally in javascript or golang:

Given a set of busy time intervals (start timestamp + end timestamp in ms), validate an incoming timeslot to be scheduled. Assume there aren't any existing overlaps.

Example:

```
const timeslots = [
  { start: 10, end: 14 },
  { start: 17, end: 21 },
  { start: 30, end: 37 },
  // ...
];
const ts = timeslots.sort((a, b) => {
  return a.start - b.start;
});

const checkValid = (inc) => {
  // validation here
};

console.log(checkValid({ start: 15, end: 16 })); // should be true
console.log(checkValid({ start: 15, end: 18 })); // should be false
console.log(checkValid({ start: 16, end: 27 })); // should be false
console.log(checkValid({ start: 8, end: 39 })); // should be false
```

And any other edge cases not described should work as well.

Comment: What do you mean by validate an incoming timeslot to be scheduled? How do you want to validate it?

Comment: @teachMe Basically the function should return `true` if the proposed `start` and `end` timestamps don't overlap any of the existing scheduled slots. If there's any overlap, it should return false.

Comment: That's a weird requirement - in javascript *or* Go. These are different languages, which one do you actually need?

Comment: @rustyx Go would be ideal but I would need to run similar checks on the frontend as well.

Answer (score 2):

If the intervals are (1) non-overlapping and (2) sorted then you can perform a [binary search](https://pkg.go.dev/sort#Search) to find the first one that lies just after the desired interval, and then simply check if the previous one overlaps with it. This would be O(logN) instead of O(N).

Example in Go:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

type Slot struct {
    start int
    end   int
}

var timeslots = []Slot{
    {start: 10, end: 14},
    {start: 17, end: 21},
    {start: 30, end: 37},
}

func checkValid(slot Slot) bool {
    i := sort.Search(len(timeslots), func(i int) bool {
        return timeslots[i].start > slot.end
    })
    return i == 0 || timeslots[i-1].end < slot.start
}

func main() {
    sort.Slice(timeslots, func(a, b int) bool {
        return timeslots[a].start < timeslots[b].start
    })

    fmt.Println(checkValid(Slot{start: 15, end: 16})) // should be true
    fmt.Println(checkValid(Slot{start: 15, end: 18})) // should be false
    fmt.Println(checkValid(Slot{start: 16, end: 27})) // should be false
    fmt.Println(checkValid(Slot{start: 8, end: 39}))  // should be false

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
validate(start, end)
for timeslot in timeslots
    if start >= timeslot["start"] and start <= timeslot["end"]
        return false
    if start < timeslot["start"] and end >= timeslot["start"]
        return false
    if end >= timeslot["start"] and end <= timeslot["end"]
        return false
return true
```

I think something like this should work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).